# Integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itx}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-x^2/2} dx?$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

This is the characteristic function of normal distribution. My instructor showed that we can evaluate this with differentiation under integral trick (to obtain and solve a differential function). He mentioned that this sort of integral can be generally solved through complex analysis but did not elaborate. Can someone show me how?

Comment: Try combining the exponential terms and completing the square in the exponent. Should reduce to a form of the Gaussian integral.

Comment: But the question is to use complex analysis.

Comment: This may help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741908/imaginary-gaussian-integral, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368186/gaussian-integral-with-imaginary-coefficients-and-wick-rotation

Comment: @DanielLi: to show that the complex and real integrals are equal, you will need [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem).